# update mongodb document using java object

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java

I have one User class like this:

```
@Document(collection = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    private String id;

    String username;

    String password;

    String description;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User[id=" + id + ", username=" + username + ", password=" + password + ", description"
                + description + "]";
    }

}
```

I am able to perform limited update. Like:

```
Query searchQuery = new Query(Criteria.where("id").is("shashi"));
        mongoDBClient.updateFirst(searchQuery, Update.update("password", "newpassword"), User.class);
```

Now if I want to update rest other fields(`username and description`) of `User` class, I need to call `updateFirst` method so many times.

I want to avoid this and pass the entire object to `updateFirst` method. Something like:

```
mongoDBClient.updateFirst(searchQuery, Update.update(userObject), User.class);
```

Basically, I want to edit all/multiple fields in one call using java POJO object. How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit/All multiple fields in one call using java POJO object, can be done as shown below

1) Query the document which need to be updated --> we get the java object

2) Do all modifications in the java object

3) Save the object

**Code:**

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("id").is("shashi"));
User user = mongoOperation.findOne(query, User.class);
//modify the user object with the properties need to be updated
//Modify password and other fields

user.setPassword("newpassword");
user.setDescription("new description");
user.setUsername("NewUserName");
//save the modified object
mongoOperation.save(user);
```